# Polymorhism - how to access method of derived class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have some problems understanding some concepts of OOP. Lets say there exist different shapes (circles, squares etc.) but they are all shapes. Therefore I can use polymorphism to store/collect all shapes in a vector, like:

```
Shape* circle = new Circle();  // inherits form Shape-class
Shape* box = new Box(); // inherits form Shape-class

vector<Shape*> list;

list.push_back(circle);
list.push_back(box);
```

But what if I want to access a specific property or method of the (form the `Shape`-class derived) classes `Box` or `Circle`, if I can acces these objects only through the `list`-vector, where they are stored via polymorphism as `Shape`-objects?

Basically, I want to do this (but this is not possible):

```
double radius = list[0]->get_radius();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a language, but your code looks C++, so I'll assume that.

Firstly you need to consider the design. You're putting some shapes (not necessarily all circles) into a collection, but then trying to call a method that is only valid for circles. What's supposed to happen when you try to get to a square? If these objects need to all be circles, you should consider putting them into a container that only contains circles, you can put your squares in another container.

If however what you want is:

```
iterate over the objects 
if the object is a circle, then call get_radius, 
if the object is not a circle, move on or do something else
```

Then you can achieve that with dynamic_cast, provided the base class has at least one virtual function.

```
Shape* shapePointer = list[0]; // get a shape from the collection some way, maybe by iterator instead
Circle* circlePointer = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(shapePointer);
if(circlePointer != nullptr)
{
    circlePointer->get_radius(); // obviously you'd want to do something with the result here
}
```

There's no way to "access the method of the derived class" from the base class - since it doesn't have information about derived classes, what we do here is test whether the base pointer actually points at an object of a particular derived class, and if so we use it as the derived class.

One needs to take care with casting, but in the above code we check whether the cast was successful, and have acceptable ways to continue whether it was or not.

A different approach is to consider giving the base class a virtual get_perimeter method which can be implemented for all the derived classes in the suitable shape-specific way.

Comment: Thanks! I added the c++ tag.